# Pass function to jquery from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

i have a problem. I'm trying to generate highchart from php. Everything was fine, but  i cant do one thing. I have to insert this code

```
 event => Array (                                          
    load => requestData (),
    )
```

The problem is that php interprets the code as a function, and if i put

```
load => 'requestData ()',
```

highcharts doesn't interpret the function. What can I do?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass it without the parentheses:

```
load => 'requestData',
```

This is the standard way of referencing a function in Javascript:  `functionName()` invokes the function and evaluates to its return value; `functionName` evaluates to the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ude in php :

```
load => 'requestData ()',
```

and in javascript :

```
eval(load);
```